# Confusion on the proof of showing that a differential form is not exact

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am trying to solve a classic problem of showing that the form $\omega = \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$ is not exact. However, I have some questions regarding the standard solutions.

Typically when I try to show that a closed form is not exact, I try to show that the integral is nonzero: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}} \omega \neq 0$. Why is it sufficient to show that $\int_{S^1} \omega \neq 0$? In other words, is it not possible for a differential form $\omega$ to have nonzero integral but a restriction to a subspace $\omega|_U$ to have an integral equal to $0$?

To compute $\int_{S^1} \omega$ can I apply Stokes' theorem via $\partial D^2 = S^1$ even though $\omega$ has a problem on $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

Comment: I think the logic is this. You use homotopy invariance of dR cohomology to turn the problem to one on $S^1$, then use Poincaré duality on $S^1$ to argue the sufficiency.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \}} \omega$ where the domain of integration is 2-dimensional but $\omega$ is a 1-form?  (Or alternatively, if the domain didn't have a typo, what do you mean by $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ (0, 0) \}$?)

Comment: A 1-form is exact if the integral over every closed curve vanishes. It is therefore non-exact if the integral doesn't vanish over at least one closed curve. That's logic: "for not all ..." is equivalent to "exists at least one such that not ..."

Comment: No, you can *not* apply Stokes' theorem when $\omega$ has a singularity inside the curve. Use a parameterization of the unit circle.

Comment: @Mr.Brown Since $R^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ can I always study a differential form under the restriction?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sorry it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @md2perpe So essentially to show that $\omega \in \Omega^1 (\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \} )$ is not exact, I need to show that there exists a closed curve $\gamma$ such that $\int_\gamma \omega \neq 0$?

Comment: @md2perpe I believe you meant "closed" and not "exact" in "a 1-form is exact if the integral over every closed curve vanishes." Of course [exact implies closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms).

Comment: @Olius. You're right, I confused the terms.

Comment: @mathlover314. That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (or the very first case of Stokes’s Theorem) tells you that if $C$ is a curve from $P$ to $Q$, then
$$\int_C df = f(Q)-f(P).$$
Hence, for any closed curve $C$, $\displaystyle\int_C df =0$.